# How do display WMS on demand directly from a webgis app

Tags: javascript, wms, cesium

I’m making a webGIS app based on Cesium Js. I have a node js server for all the server logic, a tomcat server hosting Geoserver to be able to load WMS layer on Cesium.
On my app I want to allow the user to visualize his own raster data (.tiff). So actually on the app the user can upload the data, all the informations are saved into a SQL database, the Geotiff goes to geoserver (thanks to geoserver RESTAPI) to create the store and the WMS layer.
But the problem I have now is that I want to show the wms layer on the Cesium map after the user upload the data (Specific button to load the wms).
I know how to display wms on Cesium but when I make a function to get the geoserver layer info (stored in a postgresql database) and pass the info into the WMS function, nothing appears on the map.

Any though how to make appears wms on demand by the user ?

Here is my code for the wms function :

```
testWms = document.querySelector('#wms');


// event to call on click the fetchLatestLayer function


testWms.addEventListener('click', fetchLatestLayer);


// Function to add WMS layer to the Cesium map
function addWMSLayer(storename, layername) {
  console.log(layername, storename)
  const provider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
    parameters: {
      format: 'image/png',
      transparent: 'true'
    },
    layers: `${storename}:${layername}`
    
  });


  const imageryLayer = new Cesium.ImageryLayer(provider);
  viewer.imageryLayers.add(imageryLayer);
  
}


async function fetchLatestLayer() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/latest-layer');
    const { storename, layername } = response.data;
    console.log('Got latest layer:', { storename, layername });
    addWMSLayer(storename, layername);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching latest layer:', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you access the WMS from e.g. QGIS and is it published by the GeoServer (check in the capabilities) after the user uploads a TIF?

Comment: @til_b yes the layer is published and I can access the WMS from QGIS

Comment: What does the `console.log('Got latest layer:', { storename, layername });` print - the correct info?

Comment: It print an object containing the correct layer name and store name. 
And the ```console.log(layername, storename)``` print the same layername and storename as input for the layers parameters. 
All the info are correct in the console.

Comment: Can you add the layer when you use a static layername as the layers parameter to `Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider`?

Comment: sometimes you say storename, layername and sometimes layername,storename - be sure to get the right part in the right place!